# How is this value of a slope for a parabola

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

My teacher wrote  that $$y + \frac{D}{4a} =a*(x+\frac  {b}{2a})^2$$ is the value of slope . I thought it could be instantaneous slope then since slope is of a line and not a parabola. Then , my question is how did he derive this as value of slope.

My teacher said that equate the slope to 0.
that is $dy/dx=0$

$dy/dx= 2a(x+\frac{b}{2a})$

so
$2a(x+\frac{b}{2a})=0$

so $x=-b/2a$

Comment: Can you re-format the question and write the question clearly please?

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai see now .

Comment: You must have misunderstood the teacher. What you have there is a rewriting of the equation of a parabola which makes it easy to graph the thing. The equation you have written does not tell you the (instantaneous) slope of a parabola.

Comment: If a parabola has the equation
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
and we set $D=b^2-4ac$ as its discriminant, then the equation can be written in the form
$$y+\frac{D}{4a}=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2$$
where $\left(-\frac{b}{2a},-\frac{D}{4a}\right)$ are the coordinates of the vertex of the parabola.

This has nothing to do with "slopes".

Comment: @Raffaele My teacher equated dy/dx = 0. Then , 2ax + b/a. And he said that equation the slope to 0.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Pls check my recent comment

Comment: @user15072279 You should add this to your question.

Comment: Sorry, 15072279, your comment is incomprehensible. Please try to write complete, simple, declarative sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Raffaele pointed out, what your teacher is attempting to do is to write the quadratic equation in vertex form, or to "Complete the square". Now at the vextex $\left(-\frac{b}{2a},-\frac{D}{4a}\right)$ the slope is $0$. I believe the goal is to show that you can find the $x$ value of the turning point either by completing the square or by setting the derivative to $0$ and solving for $x$.